# url with joomla folder

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I have downloaded one joomla live site folder.set up configuration file and database .But it's giving me error sever not found.

actually my url is http://local.host/foldername/

But it takes www.localhost.com/foldername/

what is the problem with my folder?what can i do for it?

Answer (score 1):

Add `www.localhost.com` to your hosts file to point to `127.0.0.1`.

On Windows it's in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\`.

Comment: @Rupali If the solution works for you, may I ask you to accept the answer by clicking the tick to the left of it?